# Android x86 select Sound Card

Tags: audio, sound-card, intel-atom, android-x86

I really really hope that someone can help me, I spent days trying to get it to work, but to no avail. So here goes:
I have a small HP Tablet (Pavilion x2) and installed Android x86. The newest version, 8.1.1 of Android x86 (64 bit) works really really good, all my apps work flawlessly, BUT I have no sound. It's a common issue with the Intel Atom Processors (mine is Intel Atom Z8300).

```
cat /proc/asound/cards
```

shows me two cards, 0 is bytchtnocodec, so it doesn't find my sound card. Also card 1 is HDMI.
So I thought, well, I'll use an external sound card. So I bought a USB sound card and it gets detected as card 2, but I still have no sound. I tried `alsa_ctl init -c 2` and it says it worked, but I still hear no sound. I tried forcing card 2 as default sound card by creating "asound.conf" in /etc but I don't have write acces there, although I am root user. I read that you should create that file and write `defaults.pcm.card 2
 defaults.ctl.card 2`, but because I can't create it, I can't do that.
I tried so much, I tried getting that access to create it; didn't work. I tried switching the sound to the USB sound card, but it didn't work. It doesn't even have to be permanent, at this point I'd be glad if it worked at all, I would accept doing the process every time I boot. 
The USB sound card gets detected and everything is on 100% in the scontrols and controls, so it HAS TO BE POSSIBLE.
Please help me! Thanks in advance!

PS: I gathered all the knowledge I showed here with googling, I don't know anything else about Linux systems and such.