# BlissOS 14 no sound

Tags: audio, sound-card

I installed BlissOS 14 today and so far everything works fine, except the sound. I've made some Google search, and everything suggested did not work. Now I have found a post ([Android x86 select Sound Card](https://superuser.com/questions/1420481/android-x86-select-sound-card)), relating to the sound issue on Android x86. I typed the first command shown on that post, and it detected the sound card. I tried to initialize the sound card using the `alsa_ctl init` command, but still there is no sound coming out. I typed different options of the command, but no success. What do I have to do to correctly initialize the sound card and make it work?

The laptop I am using is a Fujitsu Lifebook E556.

Here is an image of the detection: [image: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AE6iN4zPs89yjnY_i35gXBIDk5zXCpYl/view?usp=drivesdk]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: There are [official troubleshooting instructions](https://docs.blissos.org/knowledgebase/troubleshooting/sound-issues/). Have you tried following them yet?